# SubSonic and Paging using ROW_NUMBER ()

Tags: subsonic, paging, row-number

How to enable ROW_NUMBER () with SubSonic to do paging?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to. It is built in to the sqlquery engine. use SubSonic.SqlQuery instead of SubSonic.Query.